# Python 3.6 cvxopt.base ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, cvxopt

I am running `Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)` on a Windows 10 x64 system, with a script that attempts to load `QP_Solver` from `cvxopt`. This was working fine until today, when running the same python script gave the following error. Simply `import cvxopt` gives the same error too.

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

**Error Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nyxynyx\optimization\cvxopt_solver.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cvxopt import solvers, matrix
  File "C:\Users\nyxynyx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import cvxopt.base
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**Installed Packages**

1. `numpy==1.14.3+mkl`
2. `cvxopt==1.1.9`

These were installed using precompiled binaries from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

Inside the directory `C:\Users\nyxynyx\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cvxopt`, I see the file `base.cp36-win_amd64`.

**MinGW**

An answer to a similar question asked to look at `C:\Anaconda3\envs\foo\Library\mingw-w64\bin` where `foo` is the env name. `C:\Users\nyxynyx\Anaconda3\envs\foo\Library` contains some DLLs, not sure which one we should be looking for?

**Running the Command Prompt as an Administrator**

Running the script in an Anaconda Prompt started as an Administrator does not solve the error.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778178/import-cvxopt-base-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: @Sraw Updated question with details on how the answers in your referenced question does not help with my problem

Comment: Why are you mixing anaconda with Gohlke's binaries? This calls for trouble (although not necessarily for this task alone). Why don't you just use the anaconda-based install approach?