# DLL import error in Pycharm, but works fine outside

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I have new Anaconda and PyCharm installations on Windows machine.

Simply running

```
import numpy
```

raises

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

In similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795268/unable-to-load-dll-python-module-in-pycharm-works-fine-in-ipython), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778178/import-cvxopt-base-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)), people suggest to check that `PATH` has paths to DLLs.
In my case - it does! But instead, I have additional paths prepended to `PATH` when I start something from PyCharm. And I think this could be the problem.

When running from Anaconda prompt, `sys.path` is:

```
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\python37.zip
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\DLLs
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\lib
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

When running from python console in Pycharm, `sys.path` is the same, except that now we have two addional lines in the beginning of the file:

```
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-C\ch-0\182.4505.26\helpers\pydev
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-C\ch-0\182.4505.26\helpers\pydev
```

By the way, the initial error is raised from `C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-C\ch-0\182.4505.26\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py`.
So I think this locates the problem, yet I don't know why it arises, why it didn't happen on my other machine, and more importantly, how to fix it?

---

Technical data:

```
PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-182.4505.26, built on September 19, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 10.0

Python: 3.7, 3.6.6;

numpy: 1.15.4; 1.14.6
```

Comment: What does `python -c "import numpy;print(numpy)"` say?

Comment: `<module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\usr\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>`

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234 bug thread; has some possible workarounds until a fix is released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an open bug; [This answer](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234#focus=streamItem-27-3184933-0-0) from Jetbrains issue tracker temporarily fixed the problem for me.

> - open command line
> - activate conda venv
> - get the correct PATH value by echo %PATH%
> - open PyCharm and set new PATH value
>
>   - for Python console in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Python Console | Environment variables
>   - for running scripts in Run | Edit Configurations ... |  | Environment variables

**UPD:** The bug fixed in 2019.1

Answer (score 0):

Last I found from pydev is this workaround, which is like pycharm but from within eclipse IDE as a plugin:

> "As a note, right now the workaround can be starting Eclipse from that shell, going to the related interpreter and adding a 'PATH' environment variable to match the one which is expected to run conda (you can force environment variables for a specific interpreter)." [Link](https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/946)

This probably can be done the same way for pycharm, ie. launching pycharm from within the correct environment, and explicitly setting the path variable as well.