# import cvxopt.base --- ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I basically faced the same problem with:
[import cvxopt.base: the specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778178/import-cvxopt-base-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) when I tried to import cvxopt

And I already installed the numpy+mkl as suggested by Baokai Zhang.
But the problem is still there.
I use Python 3.5 on Pycharm.
Could anyone help me? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, and I fixed it by adding Python36\Library\bin to the System Path, for instance:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Library\bin

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing answers:

1) There's `mkl_rt.dll` which needs to be loaded.

2) It should be in your `PATH` environment variable.

3) It locates in `Library\bin` folder under your Python instance or venv.