# Cannot run import cvxopt

Tags: python, pycharm, cvxopt

I am trying to run `cvxopt` for convex optimization applications on my Pycharm, but I am having some trouble importing the library

```
import numpy
import cvxopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jsj\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition     2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jsj\PycharmProjects\ABS_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\__init__.py", line     50, in <module>
    import cvxopt.base
  File "C:\Users\jsj\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition     2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anybody help please? I am using `Python 3.6` and `Pycharm 2018.1.4`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import cvxopt.base: the specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778178/import-cvxopt-base-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: @buran I tried but doesn't work

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the error. Have you checked out: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000017460-ImportError-DLL-load-failed-The-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-